# How to simulate OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

Tags: java

I would like to know how to cause OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace exception by yourself? Is it possible to load a lot of classes and make them stay in memory for a long time.

Comment: What have you tried? Did it not work?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep appending some text to a `StringBuilder` until you will get `OutOfMemoryError`

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

while (true) {
    s.append("dummy");
}
```

You could also add some dummy class to a `List` or a `Set`, but creating new instances is more time consuming and you'll have to wait some time until you get `OutOfMemoryError`.

Also amortized time cost of insertion into an Array list will make the difference as well.

**Updated**

By default, Java 8 has unlimited maximum size for Metaspace, so as long as you don’t set the limit by using the `MaxMetaspaceSize` flag, the error should not be thrown.

Comment: But this would not cause metaspace exhasted error, correct? But since the metaspace is also on heap and this method exhausts the heapspace, I am not quite sure of the behaviour here, can someone explain this please?

Comment: @SchiduLuca *OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace* - this will cause the *heap* to exhaust, definitely not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

To create `OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace` use the `javassist.ClassPool` library. The below example will create the `Metaspace` error.

```
import javassist.ClassPool;

public class OutOfMemoryErrorMetaspace {

    //ClassPool objects hold all the CtClasses.
    static ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                  //makeClass method - Creates a new class (or interface) from the given class file.
                  Class clas = classPool.makeClass(
                               i + " outofmemory.OutOfMemoryErrorMetaspace ").toClass();
                  //Print name of class loaded
                  System.out.println(clas.getName());
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand `javaassist` is an external library. Is there a way to do that without using external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

In order to simulate `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace`, you have to load a lot of different classes.

First of all following metaspace settings have to be set:

```
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=10m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=2M
-XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=1
-XX:MaxMetaspaceExpansion=1K
-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=1
-XX:InitialBootClassLoaderMetaspaceSize=2M
```

Then the following code makes the classloader load a lot of different classes.
This is accomplished by taking the compiled bytecode of a class `mypackage.Myclass0` and adjusting to iteratively create new classes by changing the class name and adjusting the length of the class name:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String clazzBase64 ="yv66vgAAADcADAEAEm15cGFja2FnZS9NeWNsYXNzMAcAAQEAEGphdmEvbGFuZy9PYmplY3QHAAMBAApTb3VyY2VGaWxlAQANTXljbGFzczAuamF2YQEABjxpbml0PgEAAygpVgwABwAICgAEAAkBAARDb2RlACEAAgAEAAAAAAABAAEABwAIAAEACwAAABEAAQABAAAABSq3AAqxAAAAAAABAAUAAAACAAY=";

        byte[] compiledClazz = Base64.getDecoder().decode(clazzBase64);
        int classNameLength = Integer.valueOf(compiledClazz[12]);

        MyClassLoader myClassLoader = new MyClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            byte[] bytes = String.valueOf(i).getBytes();
            byte[] bytecode = new byte[compiledClazz.length + bytes.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(compiledClazz, 0, bytecode, 0, 30);
            bytecode[12] = (byte) (classNameLength + bytes.length - 1 & 0xFF);

            System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, bytecode, 30, bytes.length);
            System.arraycopy(compiledClazz, 31, bytecode, 30 + bytes.length, compiledClazz.length - 31);

            String classname = "mypackage.Myclass" + i;
            Class c = myClassLoader.getClass(classname, bytecode);
        }
    }

    public static class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
        public MyClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
            super(parent);
        }

        public Class<?> getClass(String name, byte[] code) {
            return defineClass(name, code, 0, code.length);
        }
    }
```